# Sawtooth waveform used for wireless battery charging

Tags: voltage, ac, dc, sawtooth-waveform

Why don't we use sawtooth AC waveforms instead of the sinusoidal ones? Since the rate of change of voltage is steady for a purely resistive circuit the rate of change of current is costant-> linear change of the magnetic field around so we could use it as a  battery charger or a rectangular waveform generator(from Faraday's law of induction if V = -ΔΦ/Δt , ΔΦ changes linearly over time so the induced voltage is costant).

Comment: The rate of change in a sawtooth is constant on the rising portion. The rate of change is infinite on the falling portion. Does this suggest any problems?

Comment: Ah ok thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since the rate of change of voltage is steady ... if V = -ΔΦ/Δt , ΔΦ changes linearly over time so the induced voltage is constant).

As mentioned in the comments, the rate of change in a sawtooth is constant on the sloping portion. The rate of change is infinite on the falling portion.